# Bind .unload() or .onbeforeunload() to dynamically created iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, onbeforeunload

I need to append a spinner every time the iframe unloads and clear them on iframe load. I tried to set `iframe.unload()` and `iframe.onbeforeunload()` but nothing working. Here is my code block,

```
var iframe = $('<iframe/>'), $this = $('div#iframeContainer');
iframe.attr('src', url).load(function() {
    alert('iframe onload!');
}).unload(function() {
    alert("iframe unload");
});
$this.append(iframe);
```

The jQuery `.load()` works fine for me, but `.unload()` is never called. I even tried to bind the unload event to the `iframe.contents().find('body')`, but that too didn't work.

Comment: An iframe doesn't really `unload`, only the window does that when you close it.

Comment: @adeneo: Thanks for your reply. However is there a way to attach .unload to the window inside iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
document.getElementById("your_iframe").addEventListener("unload", function(){
 //action here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. As I have mentioned that this is a dynamically created iframe, so where do I add this listener? Should it be added onLoad function of the iframe?

Comment: add it after you append it to your page..Maybe not exactly after..

Make a setTimeout of 100ms and than use it